# If $461343$ represents "Tahiti", then what island names are represented by $16343$, $38326$, and $8653$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

$4 6 1 3 4 3$ is the code for Tahiti.

Use it to find the names of the following islands:

\begin{align}
16343, \qquad 38326, \qquad 
8653.
\end{align}

> From Tahiti we have:
>
> $16343$: _aiti.
>
> $38326$: I_i_a.
>
> $8653$: _a_i.

The unknown letters are from number $1$, $2$, $5$ and $8$.
It is easy to find the islands by brute-force (Haiti, Ibiza, Bali), however I cannot find any pattern in the numbers/letters. Can you?

Comment: What's wrong with the search method?  It seems very sensible.

Comment: $h=1$ from the code word $Tahiti$.

Comment: well the first one is actually fully done by the values in Tahiti. but that aside, I'm not sure why there has to be a pattern. also could it not be that it wraps at 26 and not 9 ? is 0 included ?

Comment: maybe one should know the names of islands and find them like finding a crossword words by a few letters? in other words, there may be no pattern at all.